# Long text is cut when printed using NetSuite advanced pdf

Tags: html, pdf, freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I created a Bill of Material print out for a manufacturing company using advanced pdf. So one of the requirements is to print out the detailed manufacturing which is stored on a custom field (long text) in the assembly item record. This is done because items have different set of process each. The problem is in the print out, only a third of the manufacturing process is being printed. Normally the instruction is around 4k characters, but the pdf print out has around 1k characters only. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Is this consistent? does it happen for all BoM? Is there any markup in the description (<>)? Is it happening when you get to the end of the page? Is there any css that would limit the value?  Are you creating this with a script or using the standard BoM? I've run into long text values being truncated in the past (not with freemarker but using nlapiLookupField calls. I ended up having to load the whole record.

Comment: Yes, it is consistent. I tried deleting some of it and adding it back on different parts of the text but I still get the same results. No markup on the description. There's no css limiting values. I'm using the standard BOM.

Comment: So you should file a case. The workaround in my answer should serve until this is fixed. It the instructions are unique per BoM you could build the files via scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be experiencing a built-in Netsuite issue.

One possible workaround is that if your instructions are consistent you could pull them from a library stored in the file path. Make sure the files are "available without login"

Then you'd include them as:

```
<#include "https://system....." parse=false>
```